# Reading csv files with R with percentages as X% and varying NA characters

Tags: r, csv, import

I have the task to read csv files into R. I have 8 files with up to 70 columns.
The columns are strings, categorical values, numerical and percentages in the sense that the values are like 10% instead of 0.1

Furthermore the NAs are different in the columns sometimes it is a numerical character (e.g. 9) sometimes it is a string like 'does not apply'.

I could use some gsub synthax to get rid of the "%" sign but I guess that this is a common problem.
Furthermore I would like to avoid having to specify each column in every file whether it is of the "%" format.

Is there a package or a function that can read percentage numbers as numerical?
With the varying NAs I guess I will have to stick to a gsub solution - right?

Here is an example. With the numerical data 9 is the NA and in the third column "does not apply" is the NA.

```
stringsAsFactors=FALSE
x.numeric = c(1,2,3,9)
x.per = c("10%","20%","30%","40%")
x.categorical = c("1","2","does not apply","4")
data = data.frame(x1 = x.numeric, x2= x.per, x3 = x.categorical)
head(data)
str(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NAs you don't necessarily need to use a solution involving gsub or some of it's kin. There is an argument na.strings in read.table(), and you can specify several NA strings at the same time. For example, the example table you posted could be read in R with the following command:

```
test<-read.table("clipboard", header=T, sep="\t", na.strings=c("9", "does not apply"))
```

That takes the table from the clipboard, and converts both "9" and "does not apply" to NAs in the resulting table:

```
test
   x1  x2 x3
1  1 10%  1
2  2 20%  2
3  3 30% NA
4 NA 40%  4
```

This works fine, unless some of the columns contain, e.g., "9" as data and others have it meaning NA.

As for the percentage problem, that might be easiest to solve using the gsub method. Another solution to the percentage problem might be to define a new coersion function, and then specify the colClasses argument in `read.table()`. Something like this should work:

```
# New coersion function
setAs("character", "num_pct", function(from) as.numeric(gsub("%", "", from))/100)
# Define column classes for the columns in the table
test<-read.table("clipboard", header=T, sep="\t", na.strings=c("9", "does not apply"), 
                 colClasses=c("character", "num_pct", "character"))
```

This command now reads in the table with the specified classes for the columns, and converts the percentages in the second column of the table to decimal numbers on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution to the NA (in case one NA of a certain colums is not a valid entry for another columbn). What about reading X% numbers as numerics - thanks!

Comment: If you know where the percentage columns are located, you can use the hack I added in as an edit; specify a new column class type, and then use it.